# Can I limit the possible dtypes numpy can choose to assign to the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there is a way to have `np.array` assign only `bool`, `int`, `float`, or `object` as the dtype based on the data? I do not know the structure of the input data and it will not always contain non-numeric values, but one long string in the data will allocate way more memory to the array, often leading to a memory error. So, I want it to use the `object` dtype any time the data contains a non-numeric value.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 'x'], [1, 2, 'x' * 5000]])
>>> x.dtype
dtype('<U5000')
>>> x.size * x.itemsize
120000
>>> y = np.array([[1, 2, 'x'], [1, 2, 'x' * 5000]], dtype='O')
>>> y.size * x.itemsize
48
```

I want the dtype to be numeric when possible and I cannot set the dtypes beforehand and use a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html). A [record array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.array.html) is an improvement but could still potentially lead to memory errors.

```
>>> z = np.rec.array([[1, 2, 'x'], [1, 2, 'x' * 5000]])
>>> z.dtype
dtype((numpy.record, [('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U5000')]))
>>> z.size * z.itemsize
40032
```

Ideally, I would like to find a way to modify `np.array` to limit the dtypes that it will apply or exclude the dtypes that I do not want applied. I also need this to be using `numpy`, I cannot use something else in this case. Is this possible?

Comment: `.array` takes a `dtype` argument. Can you always start with an object array then test it and change its dtype if appropriate? Can you test the data before making the array?

Comment: `np.array` docs says default `dtype` is `the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence.`  For a mix of numbers and strings that `minimum dtype` is a string.  `object` dtype is a fall back option, that it only uses if necessary, and in the current version, it gives a `ragged array` warning.

Comment: @hpaulj My hope was to override this "minimum" requirement so that the "minimum" is `object` in my case

Comment: `pandas` has opted to use python strings, and sets the `dtype` of any column (Series) with strings to `object`.

Comment: That casting hierarchy is built into `numpy`, and I don't know any way to change that.

Comment: @wwii My data can be quite large, so I was hoping numpy could handle this during array creation. Starting with `object` is problematic for finding the best dtype. For example, downcasting from `float` to `int` is always possible even if data is lost.

Comment: What's the source of this data?  Loading from a file?  or already a list?  Why are you mixing numbers and large strings in the same array?

Comment: `recarray` is the same as `structured array` (just a slight difference in how fields can be accessed).  `np.rec.array` can deduce field dtypes, but as you found it still prefers string dtype over object.  The same would be the case when using `dtype=None` in `np.genfromtxt`.  Keep in mind that `object` dtype arrays are essentially lists.